# sort list by using minimum value

Tags: python, list, tuples

This is what i did but it didn't work:

```
def min_sorted(xs):
    copy_list= xs
    list=[]
    while copy_list:
        minimum=copy_list[0]
        for i in copy_list:
            if i < minimum:
                minimum = i
            if not i == minimum:    
                list.append(minimum)
    print (list)
```

this is what i did but it didn't work like this can some one check for me please?

```
ex: xs = [7, 8, 3, 1, 5]

min_sorted([7, 8, 3, 1, 5]) ====> [1, 3, 5, 7, 8]

xs ====>[7, 8, 3, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Are you trying to use any algorithm in particular?

Comment: there are quite a lot of problems with this code.

Comment: the code above is disaster! don't even try to run it.

Answer (score 3):

**Since you want to sort by the minimum value, it's a much better idea to use the built-in [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) method which is designed precisely for this job, rather than your own custom version:**

```
xs = [7, 8, 3, 1, 5]

def sort_list(lst):
    return sorted(lst)

print sort_list(xs)
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 8]
```

This way, it also leaves your original list untouched, too.

NOTE:

As per @Ramchandra Apte:

> Note that sorted() returns an iterator in Python 3, so if you iterate
>   over that iterator, it will be finished and no more values can be
>   produced from the iterator. So you might want to pass the output of
>   sorted() to list().

Comment: Note that `sorted()` returns an iterator in Python 3, so if you iterate over that iterator, it will be finished and no more values can be produced from the iterator. So you might want to pass the output of `sorted()` to `list()`

Comment: @RamchandraApte: Noted.

Comment: Looks like he's trying to implement a specific sort algoritm, a variant of the classicol "selection sort", I suppose for homeworks... :)

Comment: @dbra: Given the dearth of information stated in the question and the title thereof, I assumed that the OP wanted to be able to sort a list as he/she didn't state how or for what reason (shrugs). It's possible that you're correct. Thanks for your feedback, though. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def min_sort(xs):
    oxs = []
    txs = list(xs)
    while txs:
        midx = 0
        for i, x in enumerate(txs[1:]):
            if x < txs[midx]:
                midx = i+1
        oxs.append(txs.pop(midx))
    return oxs
```

Comment: ...of course the Timsort algorithm implemented in standard list.sort fuction is far more faster, but I suppose you need to implementate this variant of selection sort as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question history, this looks like a homework problem. I'll assume you're not allowed to use `sorted`, as jrd1 suggested. If you can, definitely use `sorted` instead.

[Selection Sort](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~csonline/Algorithms/Lessons/SelectionSort/index.html) sounds like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do:

```
xs = [7, 8, 3, 1, 5]
sorted_mintomax = sorted(xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

The bubblesort pushes the minimum value to the front while iterating backwards through the list in the inner loop and iterating forward in the outer loop.

```
def min_sorted(xs):
    xsort = []
    for x in xs:
        xsort.append(x)
    i = 0
    while i < len(xsort)-1:
        for j in range(len(xsort)-1, i, -1):
            if xsort[j] < xsort[j-1]:
                y = xsort[j-1]
                xsort[j-1] = xsort[j]
                xsort[j] = y
        i = i + 1
    return xsort
xs = [7,8,3,1,5]
sorted = min_sorted(xs)
print(xs)
print(sorted)
```

`OUTPUT:`

```
[7, 8, 3, 1, 5, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a soulution implemented in C, using the pattern called sorting by minimum values. It'a quite complicated, hard to understand, but let's give it a try!

```
 // 9.  SORTING BY MINIMUM VALUES

#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMBER 25   //SIZE OF THE ARRAY

int main() {
    int array[] = {56, 32, 45, 67, 723, 9, 7, 12, 545, 45, 1, 76, 345, 311, 6, 734, 87, 456, 325, 786, 34, 6, 5, 987, 3};

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER - 1; ++i) {

        int index = i;
        int value = array[i];

        for (int j = i + 1; j < NUMBER; ++j) {
            if (value > array[j]) {
                value = array[j];
                index = j;
            }
        }
        array[index] = array[i];
        array[i] = value;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < NUMBER; k++) {
        printf("%d ", array[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```